# Convert constituent string to Tree object (Stanza)

Tags: python, stanford-nlp, parse-tree

I am doing some experiments in `Python` with `Stanza` and I have converted a lot of sentences into [ParseTree](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/data_objects.html#parsetree) objects and saved them into a file like this:

```
# sent_id = Not relevant to the question
# text = Might be ok for some , but not for me
(S (NONE Might be) (OPINION_1_Negative_Standard (POLAR_EXPRESSION ok)) (NONE for some , but) (OPINION_0_Negative_Standard (POLAR_EXPRESSION not)) (NONE for) (ALL_01 (SOURCE me)))
```

And now, I want to read that file, get the strings of the *Tree* and convert them again into a `ParseTree` object, but I am not able to find how it should be done properly.

I checked [Data Conversion](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/data_conversion.html), but I can not find what I am trying to do, and the [Constituency Parser](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/constituency.html) examples show how to get the string representation but not how to convert that string into a Tree.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution reading the source code in their GitHub.

Inside the [constituency](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/stanza/tree/main/stanza/models/constituency) module, in the [tree_reader](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/stanza/blob/main/stanza/models/constituency/tree_reader.py) file there is a method called `read_trees(text)` that it does exactly what I wanted.

Regards.